# Grails Bootstrap.js dropdown search based on multiple properties

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am new to Grails and have been trying to figure out how to create a searchable select where I can search by different attributes from the list of objects in the select. I am using Grails 2.4.3 and Twitter Bootstrap.

I have a list of objects - **items**,  which has 2 attributes, **name** and **code**. I have to display the item names in the dropdown, but can search either by the name or the code.

```
<g:if test="${items?.size() > 1}">
<g:select id="itemSelect"
              name="itemSelect"
              optionKey="id"
              from="${items.sort {it.name}}"
              optionValue="${{ "${it.name} / ${it.code}"}}"
              value="${item?.id}"
              class="form-control selectpicker"
              data-live-search="true"
              data-size="10" />
</g:if>
```

What I want is to have

```
optionValue="${{ "${it.name} / ${it.code}"}}"
```

replaced by

```
optionValue="${{ "${it.name}"}}"
```

But I should still be able to search either by name or code. Currently, I can only search by both name and code if the data is displayed in optionValue.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

You'll have to include the Select2 javascript and css files as shown below and jquery, I'm also using bootstrap styling for the example.

You're making ajax calls back to a controller action which does the filtering on the 2 fields, in this example we're doing it on a domain object using criteria, wasn't sure what was in your list, we return the results as JSON.

You'll get a search box and your results will be updated on the fly.

gsp:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/select2.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/select2.min.js" ></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( "#itemSearch" ).select2({
                placeholder: "Search for an item...",
                ajax: {
                    url: "${g.createLink( controller: 'myController', action: 'listOfStuff')}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term // search term sent to action
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.name,    // what'll be shown in the drop down list
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            })
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                minimumInputLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <g:form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Item</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select id="itemSearch" name="itemSearch" class="form-control">
                    <option>Initial option</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:form>

</body>
```

Controller:

```
def listOfStuff() {
    def ret = MyDomain.createCriteria().list {
        or {
            ilike("name", "%${params.q}%")
            ilike("code", "%${params.q}%")
        }
    }
    render ret as JSON
}
```